# Not able to access child enum through interfaces in angular component

Tags: angular

```
export interface PluginConfig {
    BomgarConfigFields: PluginConfigField[];
    CustomConfigFields: PluginConfigField[];
    Appliance: string;
    Disabled: boolean;
    Name: string;
}

export interface PluginConfigField {
    Name: string;
    CodeName: string;
    Value: any;
    Required: boolean;
    Description: string;
    EncryptValue: boolean;
    CustomValidators: PluginConfigFieldValidators[];
    ValidationMessage: string;
    ValidValues: string[];
    FieldType: DataType[];
}

export enum DataType {
    text = 0,
    boolean = 1,
    select_one = 2,
    select_many = 3,
    object_list = 4,
    hidden = 5,
    text_area = 6,
    json = 7
}
```

My component looks like:

```
  createAnotherForm(controls: PluginConfig) {
    const validatorsToAdd = [];
    if (controls !== undefined) {
      for (const bomgarField of controls.BomgarConfigFields) {
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(bomgarField.FieldType.text)) {
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I am getting error at `bomgarField.FieldType.text` as
`Property 'text' does not exist on type 'DataType[]'` How to access the enums from the interface?

Comment: `DataType[]` means an _array_ of values from `DataType`. If you want the value, it's... `DateType.text`. But then what would you expect for `Object.entries(0)`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe
The main objective is I want to get the value of enum in my component but I don't know how to get that. I have tried putting FiedlType: DataType[] array for the FieldType it did not work. I tried just the FieldType: DataType it still did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
FieldType: DataType[];
```

to

```
FieldType: DataType;
```

Should fix the problem. You declared bomgarField.FieldType as an array not enum.